# Why cant I get selenium to kick in with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Im trying to test a user clicking on a button which makes an ajax call. When i click it manuallly in my browser it behaves as expected i.e. default behaviour of the button is ignored and instead it gets the results via ajax which are then added to the page.

But when i run my tests using capybara, after clicking on the button it redirects to the buttons action. It seems selenium isnt kicking in. I cant figure out why.

Is it my config? Since it works in development mode Im assuming this isnt due to my jquery code so for brevity not displaying that.

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'omniauth', '~>0.2.0'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'youtube_it'
gem 'simple_form'

# Asset template engines
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'


gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do

  gem "shoulda"  
  gem "factory_girl_rails"  
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'mocha'
end

group :development do
    gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem "autotest"
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem "capybara", :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem "launchy"
  gem "haml-rails"
  gem "database_cleaner"
end
```

or my test_helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'shoulda/rails'
require "capybara/rails"


class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  def login_in(user)
    @request.session[:user_id] = user.id
  end


  def should_redirect_unauthorized
     assert_redirected_to root_path
     assert_match /you need to login/i, flash[:alert]
  end
end


module ActionController
  class IntegrationTest
    include Capybara::DSL

    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    setup do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.start #workaround for capybara / selenium. See capybara docs
    end


    teardown do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean #workaround for capybara / selenium. See capybara docs
    end

      #signup using twitter, facebook for authentication
    def signup_using(provider)
      OmniAuth.config.add_mock(provider.to_sym, {'uid' => "123456"})

      visit '/'
      page.click_link("#{provider}_auth")

      assert_match /\/users\/\d+\/edit/, current_path
      assert page.find("#flash").has_content?("Welcome to")
    end

    #login into existing account using twitter, facebook
    def login_using(service)
      OmniAuth.config.add_mock(service.provider.to_sym, {'uid' => service.uid})
      visit '/'
      page.click_link("#{service.provider}_auth")
      assert page.find("#flash").has_content?("Welcome back")
      assert_equal rooms_path, current_path
    end

    def login_and_visit_room(service, room) 
      login_using(service)
      visit_room(room)
    end

    def visit_room(room)
      visit room_path(room)
      assert_equal room_path(@room.id), current_path
    end     
  end
end
```

or the setup blocks in my integration test

```
require 'test_helper'


class PlaylistStoriesTestTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  setup do 
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @service = @user.services.create(:provider => "twitter", :uid => "123456")
    @room = Factory(:room)
  end

  ....

 teardown do 
    Capybara.use_default_driver
      DatabaseCleaner.clean #workaround for capybara / selenium. See capybara docs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With Capybara, you should not get confused with the difference between a link (even if it looks like a button) and a button (like "submit"). You did not provide the view file contents, but I guess, you are using a button, not a link.

With capybara, you have to differentiate

```
visit '/'
click_button 'Login'
```

or

```
visit '/'
click_link 'Home'
```

See also the [Capybara-Documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons) at GitHub